# How can a facet_grid() be set up so that the y-axis only shows the uppermost value in each instance and nothing in between?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I have a facet_grid set up showing survival rates of people aboard the Titanic based on their titles.

[image]

Each row shows a title range (such as "Mr.", "Dr.", etc.).

I have set `scales="free"` within `facet_grid()`, so that each y-axis is tailored to the group which it identifies.

However, as there are lots of groups/titles, I want the y-axis on each facet grid to only show only the uppermost value and not everything in between.  For example, if 40 people died who were known as "Mr.", then I want the top of the y-axis on the "Mr." facet grid to show the value 40 and nothing else below that.  However, if only one person has died, I don't want the y-axis to read: `0.00, 0.25, 0.50, 1.00` as these "in-between" values are not of any value.

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
custom_breaks <- function(x) range(x)

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + geom_point() +
  facet_grid( cyl~., scales="free") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = custom_breaks)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way to eliminate the lowest value also (because, for my purposes, it won't be of any value and will also help to keep the screen tidy)?

Comment: custom_breaks <- function(x) max(x)

Comment: Great, this worked (almost) perfectly - the values now listed are the maximum of the y-axis itself and not the same value as the uppermost column in each particular facet grid - can it be set so that the value depicts the maximum value of the uppermost column?  If so, how can this be achieved?

Comment: one way would be to set a specific value of `expand` in the scale, and reverse the calculation for the break. The idea was discussed for scale_tufte in ggthemes, IIRC. In its simplest form: set `expand = c(0,0)` so that the axis and data have the same endpoint

Comment: @baptiste This worked perfectly - exactly what I wanted to achieve. Thank you.